# export large amount of data to excel crashes

Tags: c#, jquery, excel

I have a kendo grid in my application and i have added export to excel button to that kendo grid .

My question here is if select the small amount of data in kendo grid and when click on export button everything is working fine

but the problem is if select the large amount of  data more than 1000 rows then the web page will become  crash and it showing "Aw, Snap" Error

my environment : C#, Jquery, Kendo Grid

I have this code in my js

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
          var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
          return function(table, name) {
            if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
            var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
            window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
          }
        })()
tableToExcel("table2excel");
```

it works fine when the data is small . but if the data is large more than 1000 it crashes the browser

I heard that Chrome can only handle HREF's that are roughly 2 million characters long. So can i handle this using Blob object ? if yes can somebody let me know how to use blob object in my case ?

Please help to resolve this issue .

Comment: rise a ticket to Telerik. i did not face this type issue.

Comment: Hi vijay,
My issue is with href length.. not with the kendo grid

Comment: would please share screen shot .

Answer (score 0):

> It exports all data and custom selection using checkbox as well.

```
function excelExport() {
        var exportAll = $('.selectrow').is(":checked");
        var grid = $("#grid");
        var rows = [{
            cells: [
                { value: "column1" },
                { value: "column2" },
                { value: "column3" },
                { value: "column4" },
                { value: "column5" },
                { value: "column6" },
                { value: "column7" }
            ]
        }];
        if (exportAll) {
            var dataDource = grid.getKendoGrid();
            var trs = $("#grid").find('tr');
            for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
                if ($(trs[i]).find(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
                    var dataItem = dataDource.dataItem(trs[i]);
                    rows.push({
                        cells: [
                            { value: dataItem.column1 },
                            { value: dataItem.column2 },
                            { value: dataItem.column3 },
                            { value: dataItem.column4 },
                            { value: dataItem.column5 },
                            { value: dataItem.column6 },
                            { value: dataItem.column7 }
                        ]
                    })
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            var dataSource = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
            var trs = grid.find('tr');
            for (var i = 1; i < dataSource._data.length; i++) {
                    var dataItem = dataSource._data[i];
                    rows.push({
                        cells: [
                            { value: dataItem.column1 },
                            { value: dataItem.column2 },
                            { value: dataItem.column3 },
                            { value: dataItem.column4 },
                            { value: dataItem.column5 },
                            { value: dataItem.column6 },
                            { value: dataItem.column7 }
                        ]
                    })
            }
        }



        var workbook = new kendo.ooxml.Workbook({
            sheets: [
                {
                    columns: [
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true },
                        { autoWidth: true }
                    ],
                    title: "Exported Data Result",
                    rows: rows
                }
            ]
        });
        kendo.saveAs({ dataURI: workbook.toDataURL(), fileName: "ExportedData" });
    }
```